# How many even-indexed values are greater than the preceding value?

Tags: r, compare

I would like to know the count of `A[even number]` is bigger than `A[even number-1]`

```
>A
[1] 1 2 3 1 4 5 5 6 7
```

My code below would not work:

```
for (i in 1:length(A)){
  coun<-0
  if (length(A)%%2!=0){
    len <- length(A)-1
    for (i in 1: len){
      if (A[i+1]>A[len]){
        coun<-coun+1
      }
    }
  else if (A[i+1]>A[i]){
    coun<-coun+1  
}
}
```

In A, the count should be 3 as (A[2]>A[1],A[4]<A[3],A[6]>A[5],A[8]>A[7],A[9] would not be considered as there is no value behind it)

Comment: I doubt you need a for loop here. I would suggest looking at `diff(A)`, then `diff(A) > 0`, and then think about subsetting `diff(A) > 0` appropriately to only look at the odd-to-even differences.

Comment: I would like to know the count of `A[even number]` is bigger than `A[even number-1]`.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple ways:

```
## find the even indices and
## calculate the differences you want
even_ind = seq_along(A)[c(F, T)]
sum(A[even_ind] > A[even_ind - 1])
# [1] 3


## or, calculate all differences, 
## and take every other one
sum((diff(A) > 0)[c(T, F)])
# [1] 3
```

Comment: such a nice use of seq_along. Is it ok then to use `F` and `T`?

Comment: @tjebo I don't understand your question about `F` and `T`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I thought it was not advised to use F and T instead of FALSE and TRUE

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are safer, it's true. Up to you how concerned you want to be about bugs arising because `T` or `F` have their definitions overwritten. Here the risk seems quite low to me.